# Swift Dictionary

Tags: swift, dictionary

I'm trying to do this:

```
var myBeacons: [NSUUID: [Int]] = [NSUUID(UUIDString:"74278BDA-B644-4520-8F0C-720EAF059935"): [1,1]]
```

but I get the following error:

```
'[NSUUID: [Int]]' is not convertible to '[NSUUID: [Int]]'
```

If I do:

```
var myBeacons2: [String: [Int]] = ["74278BDA-B644-4520-8F0C-720EAF059935": [1,1]]
```

It works

Did I miss something or does it look like bug ? (I'm using Xcode 7 beta)

Comment: what happens if you remove `[NSUUID: [Int]]` and let swift infer the type?

Comment: Same cause as in many Swift questions: `NSUUID(UUIDString:)` returns an *Optional* ...

Comment: If you don't understand the error message in a "complex" statement then split it into simpler ones. `let uuid : NSUUID = NSUUID(UUIDString:"74278BDA-B644-4520-8F0C-720EAF059935")` would tell you: *error: value of optional type 'NSUUID?' not unwrapped; did you mean to use '!' or '?'?*

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Since not every `String` is a valid UUID the initialiser can fail. Thus the initialiser returns an `Optional<NSUUID>`. This to encourage code safety.
Depending on your needs you might check that you supplied a valid `String` for an UUID as follow:

```
let givenString = "74278BDA-B644-4520-8F0C-720EAF059935"
var myBeacons: [NSUUID: [Int]] = [:]
if let uuid = NSUUID(UUIDString: givenString) {
    // Here we are sure that the uuid is valid 
    myBeacons[uuid] = [1, 1]
}
```

Comment: In this case of a fixed compiled-in UUID string (as in the question) I actually would prefer the forced unwrapping. An invalid UUID would be a  *programming error* and should be detected as soon as possible and not "hidden".

Answer (score 2):

As Martin points out, `NSUUID(UUIDString:)` returns an optional. You need to unwrap it:

var myBeacons:  = [
NSUUID(UUIDString:"74278BDA-B644-4520-8F0C-720EAF059935")!: [1,1]]

(Note the exclamation point after the call to the NSUUID initializer.)

I tested that under Xcode 6.3.2 and it works. I Haven't tested it under Xcode 7 though.

### Edit:

In fact it would be better to use optional binding as outlined in @MatteoPiombo's answer. You should accept his answer since it gives you the most robust solution. (I'm voting for his answer. It's the best answer so far)

Answer (score 0):

`convenience init?(UUIDString string: String)` returns an optional, try unwrap it as follow:

`var myBeacons: [NSUUID: [Int]] = [NSUUID(UUIDString:"74278BDA-B644-4520-8F0C-720EAF059935")!: [1,1]]`

Comment: You and I gave the same answer, but Matteo's answer is better still.